# Do activities in iframe contribute to search history?

Tags: html, search, iframe

When you search anything in a browser it will be saved in your search history and that can be used for, e.g. displaying relevant ads to you.
I was wondering, if say you have an iframe linking to another website, will that contribute to your search history?
i.e. If I make a webpage where the user can enter a URL into a text input and the iframe loads the URL entered, will that count in your search history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the iframes does not show up in the browser history as your browser history has a history of the pages visited.

If you want to save it in the browser history (depending on the browser) you can do it via javascript pushState, however you might encounter the origin errors. This will only work for the same origin websites.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Please note many websites block iframing them in your website via header: X-Frame-Options:SAME-ORIGIN due to security (for example google.com, youtube.com)